# Retrieve multiple key array from to mysql in key value pair

Tags: mysql

i have the data below store in mysql database, but I having problem to retrieve in desire form

here is my data

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | contact_0_type | phone |
| 2 | contact_0_value | 1234567890 |
| 3 | contact_1_type | email |
| 4 | contact_1_value | x@example.com |

this is query im trying to use but failed

```sql
SELECT
    t1.value AS type,
    t2.value AS value,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.key, '_', 2),
    CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.key, '_', 2), '_value')
FROM
    settings AS t1
JOIN
    settings AS t2
    ON t1.key = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.key, '_', 2), '_value')
WHERE
    t1.key LIKE 'contact_%_type'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Seems to me a small redesign of the table is required here rather than a more complex query

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for reply, how would you suggest? and why is that redesign is needed?

Comment: Redesign because you have made fetching data from this table unnecessary complicated

Comment: @RiggsFolly so what u suggest is to make a `contacts` table with `type` and `value` columns?

Answer (score 0):

Table redesign suggestion

| id | key | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | contact_0_type | phone | 1234567890 |
| 2 | contact_1_type | email | x@example.com |

Now its a simple

```
SELECT * FROM Table t
WHERE  t.key LIKE 'contact_%_type'
```

Could even order by `key` to get them in order of priority. Remember there is no underlying sort order on rows in a table so you have to ORDER the resultset yourself

```
ORDER BY key
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, i know this design is better, but i my case, the table is just contain around 1-3 records, and i want to hold data in key-value pair, so i can store other settings data too

Comment: This is in key-value pair, yours is not

Comment: sorry to confuse you, the type is also a value

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the correct way to get the desired result.

```
SELECT
    settings.`key` AS `type_key`, settings.`value` AS `type`, t3.`key` AS value_key, t3.`value`
FROM
    settings
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        t2.key AS `key`, t2.value
    FROM
        settings AS t2
    WHERE
        t2.key LIKE 'contact_%_value'
    ) AS t3 ON t3.`key` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(settings.`key`, '_', 2), '_value')
WHERE
    settings.`key` LIKE 'contact_%_type'
```

Instead of joining directly with same table, I have to use subquery

Thank you